# Post views stopped updating on WP backend posts list

Tags: posts

post views have stopped updating on backend posts list page, no changes were made to core files, or theme updates etc when this happened.

Any ideas on debugging this?

I have installed a post views plugin since, which works fine.

Comment: I suspect the post views plugin has hijacked the core functionality. If you deactivate the plugin, does the original functionality work?

Comment: are you saying installing the post views plugin fixed the issue or that the plugin has broken? Questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here, and WP doesn't have page view count functionality built in. Can you edit your question to make it clearer?

Comment: How are you counting the post views? Does your site have any caching - are page views actually making it to the backend or being served from a cache first?

Comment: Caleb No plugings were updated or should have effected this.

@TomJNowell No, that the plugin works which I installed after the mail post view count stopped counting. It is built in, there is a column on the backend posts page.

Rup caching is enabled as will all wordpress sites.

Comment: There is no mail post view count functionality in WordPress unless you install a plugin or it is a part of your theme. The only way I can see this happening is if you are not using the open source WordPress project and your site is hosted on Wordpress.com which has additional closed source software present to add features not normally available without plugins.

Comment: Note though that this question was closed as off topic. You should identify where this counter that stopped working came from, either your theme, a plugin, or your host, then contact their support

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for the information Tom, it must be the theme. Hard to believe wordpress doesn't have a post/page view counter built in!

Comment: that functionality is quite difficult to correctly do and has special storage requirements, simply storing a counter will give duplication or undercounting based on how popular the site is, and caching can mess it up entirely. Not that it isn't possible, but you need external services. If you are a wp.com customer they provide some of that for you, giving the impression it's built in, I wouldn't trust any counters to be accurate that are powered by a theme or plugin without some connection to dedicated analytics software though